# Preserving order of occurrence with size() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, dataframe

I would like to preserve the order of my DataFrame when using the .size() function. My first DataFrame is created by choosing a subset of a larger one:

```
df_South = df[df['REGION_NAME'] == 'South']
```

Here is an example of what the DataFrame looks like:

[image]

With this DataFrame I count the occurrences of each unique 'TEMPBIN_CONS' variable.

```
South_Count = df_South.groupby('TEMPBIN_CONS').size()
```

I would like to maintain the order that exists using the SORT column. I created this column based on the order I would like my 'TEMPBIN_CONS' variable to appear after counting. I can't seem to get it to appear in the proper order though. I've tried using .sort_index() on South_Count and it does not change order that groupby() creates.

Ultimately this is my solution for fixing the axis ordering of a bar plot I am creating of South_Count. As it is the ordering is very difficult to read and would like it to appear in a logical order.

For reference South_Count, and subsequently the axis of my bar plot appears in 
this order:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
South_Count = df_South.groupby('TEMPBIN_CONS', sort=False ).size()
```

Looks as though your data is sorted as string.